# LST significance testing

Tags: arcmap, google-earth-engine, land-surface-temperature

I'm new in mapping and coding in Google Earth Engine, can you significant test two LST maps(in TIFF format) in Google Earth Engine using Mann-Kendall? I tried to do it and I encountered many errors, this is my work so far.

```js
var image = image1.add(image2);

var imageCollection = ee.ImageCollection([image1, image2]);
Map.addLayer(imageCollection, {}, 'coll');

var afterFilter = ee.Filter.lessThan({
  leftField: 'system:time_start',
  rightField: 'system:time_start'
});

var joined = ee.ImageCollection(ee.Join.saveAll({
  matchesKey: 'after',
  ordering: 'system:time_start'
}).apply({
  primary: imageCollection,
  secondary: imageCollection,
  condition: afterFilter
}));

var sign = function(i, j) {
  return ee.Image(j).neq(i)
      .multiply(ee.Image(j).subtract(i).clamp(-1,1)).int();
};

var kendall = ee.ImageCollection(joined.map(function(current) {
  var afterCollection = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(current.get('after'));
  return afterCollection.map(function(image) {
    return ee.Image(sign(current, image)).unmask(0);
  });
}).flatten()).reduce('sum',2);

var palette = ['red','white','green'];
Map.addLayer(kendall, {palette: palette}, 'kendall');

var slope = function(i, j) {
  return ee.Image(j).subtract(i)
    .divide(ee.Image(j).date().difference(ee.Image(i).date(), 'days'))
    .rename('slope')
    .float();
};

var slopes = ee.ImageCollection(joined.map(function(current) {
  var afterCollection = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(current.get('after'));
  return afterCollection.map(function(image) {
    return ee.Image(slope(current, image));
  });
}).flatten());

var sensSlope = slopes.reduce(ee.Reducer.median(), 2);
Map.addLayer(sensSlope, {palette: palette}, 'sensSlope');

// Rest of the code...

// Rest of the code...

var epochDate = ee.Date('1970-01-01');
var sensIntercept = imageCollection.map(function(image) {
  var epochDays = image.date().difference(epochDate, 'days').float();
  return image.addBands(epochDays.float().rename('epochDays'));
}).reduce(ee.Reducer.median(), 2);
Map.addLayer(sensIntercept, {}, 'sensintercept');

var groups = kendall.map(function(i) {
  var matches = kendall.map(function(j) {
    return i.eq(j);
  }).sum();
  return i.multiply(matches.gt(1));
});

var group = function(array) {
  var length = array.arrayLength(0);
  var indices = ee.Image([1])
    .arrayRepeat(0, length)
    .arrayAccum(0, ee.Reducer.sum())
    .toArray(1);
  var sorted = array.arraySort();
  var left = sorted.arraySlice(0, 1);
  var right = sorted.arraySlice(0, 0, -1);
  var mask = left.neq(right)
    .arrayCat(ee.Image(ee.Array([[1]])), 0);
  var runIndices = indices.arrayMask(mask);
  var groupSizes = runIndices.arraySlice(0, 1)
    .subtract(runIndices.arraySlice(0, 0, -1));
  return groupSizes;
};

var factors = function(image) {
  return image.expression('b() * (b() - 1) * (b() * 2 + 5)');
};

var groupSizes = group(groups.toArray());
var groupFactors = factors(groupSizes);
var groupFactorSum = groupFactors.arrayReduce('sum', [0])
  .arrayGet([0, 0]);

var count = joined.count();

var kendallVariance = factors(count)
  .subtract(groupFactorSum)
  .divide(18)
  .float();
Map.addLayer(kendallVariance, {}, 'kendallVariance');

// Compute Z-statistics.
var zero = kendall.multiply(kendall.eq(0));
var pos = kendall.multiply(kendall.gt(0)).subtract(1);
var neg = kendall.multiply(kendall.lt(0)).add(1);

var z = zero
  .add(pos.divide(kendallVariance.sqrt()))
  .add(neg.divide(kendallVariance.sqrt()));
Map.addLayer(z, {min: -2, max: 2}, 'z');

// Compute P-values.
var p = ee.Image(1).subtract(eeCdf(z.abs()));
Map.addLayer(p, {min: 0, max: 1}, 'p');

// Pixels that can have the null hypothesis (there is no trend) rejected.
// Specifically, if the true trend is zero, there would be less than 5%
// chance of randomly obtaining the observed result (that there is a trend).
Map.addLayer(p.lte(0.025), {min: 0, max: 1}, 'significant trends');
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] the Question to specify the error(s) you encountered (as text, in the body of the Question).